# Пуш изменения в другую ветку

Tags: git

У меня нельзя лить изменения напрямую в мастер. и надо что-то предпринять, чтобы эти изменения запушить в отдельную ветку. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вот эта статейка когда-то мне очень помогла, советую к прочтению: https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/187-git-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cоздаём локально новую ветку и переключаемся на неё сразу (за переключение отвечает `-b`):

```
git checkout -b [branch_name]
```

Делаем свои изменения и коммитим их.
Пушим свою ветку на удаленный репозиторий:

```
git push [remote_name] [branch_name]
```

`[remote_name]` - название вашего удалённого репозитория

`[branch_name]` - название вашей ветки

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто указать ветку новую вот так:

```
git push origin master:new-branch-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Создать отдельную ветку и закомитить в неё. После этого можно и запушить.